# React-Query Handle multiple query keys updates in multiple views after mutation

Tags: reactjs, react-query

## Context

I'm working on a "Drive System" project (a simplified Google Drive clone) where a user can organize media into folders and playlists. The Drive contains a page with the hierarchical structure (like "My Drive" on Google Drive), a page with recently created media, a page with favorite media and a page with media shared with other users. Every time a user go to a page, I do a request to get fresh data. For this project, I'm using React-query to manage server data.

## Problem

Let's take a simple case. Let's say I want to rename a media file. I have a MediaComponent which handle all operation in the media object. This MediaComponent is used to render the media object in every pages on the drive. Each page have is own query key :

- My Drive :  ['folders id content'],
- Latest Medias : ['medias recent'],
- Favourite Medias : ['medias favorites'],
- Shared With Others : ['medias shared-with-others']

Every time a user rename a media, I need to update all this queries to have fresh data. So how I can handle my mutation response to update the data without making too many request ?

## Some of my current code

All queries related to medias :

```ts
export const mediaQueries = {
    all: () => ['medias'],
    latest: () => queryOptions({ // Latest Medias
        queryKey: [...mediaQueries.all(), 'recent'],
        queryFn: fetchLatestMedias
    }),
    favorites: () => queryOptions({ // Favourite Medias
        queryKey: [...mediaQueries.all(), 'favorites'],
        queryFn: fetchMediasFavorites
    }),
    sharedWithMe: () => queryOptions({
        queryKey: [...mediaQueries.all(), 'shared-with-me'],
        queryFn: fetchMediasSharedWithMe
    }),
    sharedWithOthers: () => queryOptions({ // Shared With Others
        queryKey: [...mediaQueries.all(), 'shared-with-others'],
        queryFn: fetchMediasSharedWithOthers
    })
};
```

All queries related to "My Drive" page :

```ts
export const folderQueries = {
    all: () => ['folders'],
    root: () => queryOptions({
        queryKey: [...folderQueries.all(), 'detail', 'root'],
        queryFn: fetchRootFolder,
        staleTime: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
    }),
    content: (id?: string) => queryOptions({ // My Drive
        queryKey: [...folderQueries.all(), 'content', id],
        queryFn: () => fetchFolderContent(id!),
        enabled: !!id
    }),
    filter: (id ?: string, filters?: string|null) => queryOptions({
        queryKey: [...folderQueries.all(), 'detail', id, filters],
        queryFn: () => fetchSearchInFolder(id!, filters!),
        enabled: id !== undefined && filters !== null
    })
};
```

I have a useUpdateMediaMutation which handle update a media object in the server :

```tsx
const useUpdateMedia = () => {
    const mutation = useMutation(
        {
            mutationFn: async ({ id, name } : DriveRenameData) => {
                const response = await patch<MediaHead>('/media/head', { data: { id, name } });
                return response.data;
            },
            onSuccess: (response) => {
                // What to do here ??
            },
            onError: () => {
               // Handle errors
            }
        });

    return mutation;
```

This mutation is called in a `MediaComponent` when a user submit a form.

## Solution 1 : Update all queries keys manually

I tried to update all queries keys manually, but it's a bit difficult because each query can has is own data structure. And if I want to add a new page with a new query key in the futur, I need to go in every mutation and handle the new key.

## Solution 2 : Invalidate queries

Seems to be the simpliest solution. When an user rename a media, a mutation is perform to send the new data to the server. During the mutation, I'm doing a optimistic update (via UI) to reflect the new name on the media and when the mutation is over, I invalidate all queries related.

```tsx
const useUpdateMedia = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const mutation = useMutation(
        {
            mutationFn: async ({ id, name } : DriveRenameData) => {
                const response = await patch<MediaHead>('/media/head', { data: { id, name } });
                return response.data;
            },
            onSettled: async (response) => {
                await queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey: mediaQueries.all()});
                await queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey: folderQueries.all()});
            },
            onError: () => {
               // Handle errors
            }
        });

    return mutation;
```

In MediaComponent

```tsx
const MediaElement = (props: MediaElementProps) => {
    // Mutations
    const { mutate: updateMedia, isPending, variables } = useUpdateMediaMutation();

    const mediaName = isPending ? variables.name : props.data.name;

    return <div
        className="MediaComponent"
    >
    {/** Rendu du média */}
    </div>;
```

It's seems clean but that means making an additional query just to update a name. And if the user came to that page again, a new request will be made to get fresh data. So it's a bit overkill to me. Especially for the folder query, which is quite costly.

So I tried a variant of this solution. I don't invalidate queries because when a user come to that page again I automatically fetch fresh data. Because all queries as a staleTime to 0. But when a user come again, he get the old data (because we don't update the query cache) while the new data is retrieved. I don't know if it's very good for user experience.

## Solution 3 : Use a global state manager and handle data locally

I have datas that I share in several queries. It seems logical to me to store everything in a global state and to rely only on this one. Each time I make a query or a mutation, I update this global state. And instead of drawing directly from the query result, I retrieve the data from the global state.

```tsx
const useUpdateMedia = () => {
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const { updateMedias } = useMediathequeActions();
    const mutation = useMutation(
        {
            mutationFn: async ({ id, name } : DriveRenameData) => {
                const response = await patch<MediaHead>('/media/head', { data: { id, name } });
                return response.data;
            },
            onSuccess: async (response) => {
                // Update a global state
                updateMedias(response);
            },
            onError: () => {
               // Handle errors
            }
        });

    return mutation;
```

```ts
import { create } from 'zustand';
import { MediathequeFolder } from '../types/folder.model';
import { MediathequeMedia } from '../types/media.model';
import { MediathequePlaylist } from '../types/playlist.model';

interface UseMediathequeStore {
    folders: MediathequeFolder[];
    medias: MediathequeMedia[];
    playlists: MediathequePlaylist[];
    actions: {
        updateMedias: (...newMedias :MediathequeMedia[]) => void;
        updateFolders: (...newFolders :MediathequeFolder[]) => void;
        updatePlaylists: (...newPlaylists :MediathequePlaylist[]) => void;
    }
}

const useMediathequeStore = create<UseMediathequeStore>((set, get) => ({
    folders: [],
    medias: [],
    playlists: [],
    actions: {
        updateMedias: (...newMedias: MediathequeMedia[]) => {
            const oldMedias = get().medias;

            newMedias.forEach((newMedia) => {
                const index = oldMedias.findIndex(m => m.id === newMedia.id);
                if (index === -1) {
                    oldMedias.push(newMedia);
                } else {
                    oldMedias[index] = {
                        ...newMedia
                    };
                }
            });
            set((state) => ({ medias: [...oldMedias] }));
        },
        updateFolders: (...newFolders: MediathequeFolder[]) => {
            const oldFolders = get().folders;

            newFolders.forEach((newFolder) => {
                const index = oldFolders.findIndex(f => f.id === newFolder.id);
                if (index === -1) {
                    oldFolders.push(newFolder);
                } else {
                    oldFolders[index] = {
                        ...newFolder
                    };
                }
            });
            set((state) => ({ folders: [...oldFolders] }));
        },
        updatePlaylists: (...newPlaylists: MediathequePlaylist[]) => {
            const oldPlaylists = get().playlists;

            newPlaylists.forEach((newPlaylist) => {
                const index = oldPlaylists.findIndex(p => p.id === newPlaylist.id);
                if (index === -1) {
                    oldPlaylists.push(newPlaylist);
                } else {
                    oldPlaylists[index] = {
                        ...newPlaylist
                    };
                }
            });
            set((state) => ({ playlists: [...oldPlaylists] }));
        }
    }

}));

// Atomic selectors
export const useFolders = () => useMediathequeStore(state => state.folders);
export const useMedias = () => useMediathequeStore(state => state.medias);
export const usePlaylists = () => useMediathequeStore(state => state.playlists);

// Actions
export const useMediathequeActions = () => useMediathequeStore(state => state.actions);

export default useMediathequeStore;
```

```tsx
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { folderQueries } from '../mediatheque.queries';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useMediathequeActions } from '../../../store/mediatheque';

const useLoadFolderContent = (folderId ?: string) => {
    const query = useQuery(folderQueries.content(folderId));
    const { data: currentFolder, isFetching } = query;

    const { updateMedias, updateFolders, updatePlaylists } = useMediathequeActions();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (currentFolder && !isFetching) {
            updateMedias(...currentFolder.children.medias);
            updateFolders(...currentFolder.children.folders);
            updatePlaylists(...currentFolder.children.playlists);
        }
    }, [currentFolder, isFetching]);

    return query;
};

export default useLoadFolderContent;
```

```tsx
const MyDrivePage = (props: MyDrivePageProps) => {
    // Get Folder Id from Url
    const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
    const folderId = searchParams.get('folder');

    // List folder content
    const { isLoading } = useLoadFolderContent(folderQueries.content(folderId));

    const allMedias = useMedias();

    // Get only medias from the current folder
    const medias = allMedias.filter(m => m.parent.id === folderId);

    return <div
        className="MyDrive"
    >
                {/** Render folders */}
                {/** Render medias */}
                <div className="Drive__container--medias">
                    {medias.length > 0 &&
                    medias.map((media) => {
                        return <MediaComponent
                            key={media.id}
                            className="forceLandscape"
                            data={media}
                        />;
                    })
                    }
                </div>

                {/** Render playlists */}
                }
    </div>;
```

This seems to me to be the most appropriate solution. The only problem is the risk of accumulating a lot of elements in memory. And each time I render, I have to dip into the global state and filter the results to get only what I need.

I know there's no such thing as a perfect solution. But I wanted your advice on the best way forward.

I hope I was clear !

Comment: Solution 4: When a file is renamed, perform the server mutation and then find that object in the local query client cache(s) and change its name wherever it exists.

Comment: Would you recommend solution 1? I don't have a specific media query key. I mean, I don't have a ["medias id"] key. So when I update the data, i need to update all related queries. So indeed, when I retrieve the data (whatever the query), I could add an entry for each media data in the query cache. In the end, it's the same process as solution 3.

Comment: It’s similar, but not the same as solution 3. react query is itself a state management tool, I don’t know why you’d layer zustand over the top of it. Thats asking for trouble. Whenever you retrieve query data, it’s already in the cache, you don’t need to add it. You just need to find the file that you updated amongst the queries in the cache and make sure that if it exists anywhere else, its name is updated there as well https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/framework/react/guides/optimistic-updates#updating-a-list-of-todos-when-adding-a-new-todo

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're advising me to update all my queries caches where my object exist (like Solution 1) ?

Comment: Ah yes, it wasn’t clear to me that that’s what you meant by solution 1. Use a helper function - renameFileInCache - which should alleviate repetitiveness and you should only ever have to modify this function when you create a new page and only ever have to call this function in the rename mutations.